# Ruby: how I get the instance from an bound method

Tags: ruby

in ruby I can bind a method to a receiver (instance):

```
class TEST
  def meth
  end
end
bound_method = TEST.new.method(:meth)
```

**Question**: How I can get the reveiver from a bound method back?

possible solution, found in docs:

```
/*
 *  call-seq:
 *     binding.receiver    -> object
 *
 *  Returns the bound receiver of the binding object.
 */
static VALUE
bind_receiver(VALUE bindval)
{
    const rb_binding_t *bind;
    GetBindingPtr(bindval, bind);
    return vm_block_self(&bind->block);
}
```

Comment: While I understand your question, why are you not just capturing the instance at creation? You can then access the methods of it afterwards

Comment: CC jad → because I have a library and I get the "bound method" as callback from external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can get the reveiver from a bound method back?

If you take a look at [the documentation of `Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html), you will find the method [`Method#receiver`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-receiver), which returns the bound receiver of the `Method` object:

> ## `receiver` → `object`
>
> Returns the bound receiver of the method object.
>
> ```ruby
> (1..3).method(:map).receiver # => 1..3
> ```